# SQL to rearrange characters in a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction on something... To make a long story short, my work doesn't have a DB Admin, and since I'm over on the server team, somehow SQL DBs have fallen in my lap, though I'm pretty amateur in my experience.  Anyway, we have DBs for clients, and a certain varchar(100) column (called Path) contains a string of characters that lists a path to image files in a format like this:

```
\\ImageServer\YYYY\CLIENTNUMBER\YYYYMMDD\YYYYYMMDD####\
```

where the "####" is a batch number of a bunch of images so an example would be:

```
\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\
```

The issue is that this doesn't match our folder structure for this client... they want their last folder to be in "MMDDYYYY####".  So that's what we've been outputting them as... which doesn't align with the older SQL data.

Due to this issue, a program we have that reads the SQL database isn't displaying the images, and the easiest fix is going to be alter the SQL database so that the last folder in that string reads in MMDDYYYY#### format instead of YYYYMMDD#### format.  Also, this only affects data older than 2020 (when the change took place).

In the end, I want to have that column be like this:

```
\\ImageServer\YYYY\CLIENTNUMBER\YYYYMMDD\MMDDYYYY####\
```

which is basically taking that last folder in the path, and changing around the first 8 numbers so instead of "YYYYMMDD####", it is "MMDDYYYY####".

So in that example I posted earlier, this:

```
\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\
```

would become this:

```
\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030520190012\
```

So I suppose I'm looking for something that would be like:

```
WHERE (Path LIKE '\\ImageServer\2019\0121\%')
```

and then some cool code that would rearrange the numbers.  Then I'd change the year in that LIKE command and run it for each affected year.  I'm just not sure how to rearrange them...  Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.  I've tried doing some searches, but mostly what I find is how to rearrange specific DateTime data, which this isn't, or how to rearrange strings alphabetically.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: SO you want to take the last 4 numbers and move them to the first 4 in the last part of your path?  As long as the lengths are always the same (you always use leading zeros for 1 digit month like 01.  Then you can do it with substring and len functions.  But if you can post what you have tried and some reproducible examples to test with.

Comment: Why doing such a change in the database data ? Can't you use a view to satisfy customer delirium ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if I can provide additional details... part of what I provided had some information changed due to it being company & client information.  Mostly I guess I was looking for someone to steer me in the direction on how I can take something like "20190305\201903050012" and make it "20190305\030520190012".  

As for why the change needs to be made in the SQL database, I'm trying to keep it simple, but basically a program points to this DB to pull that path to load the image into the program.  While the client doesn't see the folder structure, that's how they want it.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do with the integrated function CONCAT SUBSTRING and REVERSE :

```
DECLARE @PATH VARCHAR(100) = '\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\'

SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(@PATH, LEN(@PATH) - 13),   
              REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@PATH), 6, 2)),
              REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@PATH), 8, 2)),
              REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@PATH), 10, 4)),
              '\')
```

Comment: you should note this assumes that all client numbers are exactly 4 digits

Comment: This looks pretty much exactly like what I'm looking for!  Now I just need to find a way to alter the DECLARE with some wildcards so that it can apply to every cell in the column so all the folders change rather than just "201903050012".

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the last directory in the path is always 12 characters, YYYYMMDD####, and ends with a slash.

Using [RIGHT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [SUBSTRING()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [CONACT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [STUFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [REPLACE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DECLARE @testdata TABLE
(
    [Path] VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @testdata (
                          [Path]
                      )
VALUES ( '\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\' )
     , ( '\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903060012\' )
     , ( '\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903070012\' );

SELECT *
     , RIGHT([Path], 13) --Gets the last part of the path
     , SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 1, 4) --Year
     , SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 5, 2) --Month
     , SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 7, 2) --Day
     , CONCAT(SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 5, 2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 7, 2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 1, 4))  --use above to reformat the date
     --Use Stuff to replace the original YYYYMMDD with the reformatted MMDDYYYY date
     , STUFF(RIGHT([Path], 13), 1, 8, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 5, 2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 7, 2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 1, 4)))
     --Then replace
     , REPLACE([Path], RIGHT([Path], 13), STUFF(RIGHT([Path], 13), 1, 8, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 5, 2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 7, 2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 1, 4)))) AS UpdatedPath
FROM   @testdata;
```

Above is just showing how we can break down the string using each of those functions and put it back together to get the updated path:

```
Path                                                                                                  UpdatedPath
------------------------------------------------- ------------- ---- ---- ---- -------- ------------- -----------------------------------------------
\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\    201903050012\ 2019 03   05   03052019 030520190012\ \\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030520190012\
\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903060012\    201903060012\ 2019 03   06   03062019 030620190012\ \\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030620190012\
\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903070012\    201903070012\ 2019 03   07   03072019 030720190012\ \\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030720190012\
```

Then the update statement would be something like:

```
UPDATE @testdata
SET    [Path] = REPLACE([Path], RIGHT([Path], 13), STUFF(RIGHT([Path], 13), 1, 8, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 5, 2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 7, 2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT([Path], 13), 1, 4))))
WHERE  [Path] LIKE '\\ImageServer\2019\0121\%';

SELECT *
FROM   @testdata;


Path
------------------------------------------------
\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030520190012\
\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030620190012\
\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030720190012\
```

I would suggest ensuring you have up to date backups of the databases and test it in a dev or test environment before running it in your production systems.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = '\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\';

SELECT  NewString = 
  STUFF(@string,p.Pos,12,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@string,p.Pos+4,2),SUBSTRING(@string,p.Pos+6,2),
           SUBSTRING(@string,p.Pos,4), SUBSTRING(@string,p.Pos+8,4)))
FROM        (VALUES(PATINDEX('%\'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',12)+'\', @string)+1)) AS p(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string,p.Pos,12)))                         AS dt(Txt);
```

Returns: \ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030520190012\

**Against a table:**

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = '\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\';

DECLARE @strings TABLE(SomeId INT IDENTITY, OldString VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT @strings VALUES 
  ('\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\'),
  ('\\ImageServer\2019\0122\20190305\202005228823\'),
  ('\\ImageServer\2019\0225\20190305\202106119992\');

SELECT
  s.SomeId, s.OldString, f.NewString
FROM @strings AS s
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT  NewString = 
    STUFF(s.OldString,p.Pos,12,
      CONCAT(SUBSTRING(s.OldString,p.Pos+4,2), SUBSTRING(s.OldString,p.Pos+6,2),
             SUBSTRING(s.OldString,p.Pos,4),   SUBSTRING(s.OldString,p.Pos+8,4)))
  FROM        (VALUES(PATINDEX('%\'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',12)+'\',s.OldString)+1)) AS p(Pos)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(s.OldString,p.Pos,12)))                        AS dt(Txt)
) AS f(NewString);
```

**Results:**

```
SomeId  OldString                                        NewString
------- ------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------
1       \\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\   \\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030520190012\
2       \\ImageServer\2019\0122\20190305\202005228823\   \\ImageServer\2019\0122\20190305\052220208823\
3       \\ImageServer\2019\0225\20190305\202106119992\   \\ImageServer\2019\0225\20190305\061120219992\
```

Comment: Alan, good solution. Please modify it to make it working with a DB table. You can copy the DDL from my answer.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - I updated my post to include the logic against a table.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution. It will work on SQL Server 2017 and later.

It is based on XML and XQuery. Their data model is based on **ordered sequences**. Exactly what we need for the task.

The algorithm does the following steps:

1. Tokenizing UNC string based on the backslash as XML data type.
2. Last token is reformatted to a desired date format via FLWOR expression.
3. Composing UNC back.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, UNC VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (UNC) VALUES
('\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\'),
('\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\202103090012\');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '\';

SELECT ID, UNC
    , '\\' + REPLACE(TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(TRIM(@separator FROM UNC), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
            ']]></r></root>' AS XML)
    .query('
        for $x in /root/r/text()
        return if ($x is (/root/r[last()]/text())[1]) then 
            concat(substring($x,5,4), substring($x,1,4), substring($x,9,4))
            else string($x)
    ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
    , SPACE(1), @separator) + @separator AS [after]
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                      UNC                       |                     after                      |
+----+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | \\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\ | \\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030520190012\ |
|  2 | \\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\202103090012\ | \\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030920210012\ |
+----+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: but why use xml there are string functions to do this?

Comment: @Hogan, string parsing is very fragile. One single space, or different directory lengths in the UNC, or missing trailing backslash will break it. Tokenization is much more reliable.

Comment: and also much slower.  The right way to fix this is at the creation of the string -- we all know that.

Comment: @Hogan, it is a one time run process. A mantra of  'It's gotta be super fast' is irrelevant. Reliability is much more important. What was the reason to down-vote the suggested solution? There are always many ways to skin the cat.

Comment: I don't know why you think I down voted.  I also don't see anything about this being a one time solution.

Comment: @Hogan,  Thanks for the clarifications. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. This will use CHARINDEX, SUBSTRING, REVERSE, LEN, and LEFT to derive to the final output. This code will be dynamic and will change based on Length of the Path. I put this together real fast, but I am sure it can be cleaned up a bit to make it less complex.

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE ([Path] VARCHAR(100)
                    ,[FixedPath] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @TBL
([Path])
VALUES('\\ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\')
,('\\ImageServer\2020\15896215\20200606\20200606852358\')
,('\\ImageServer\2021\753159\20211209\20211209002585')

UPDATE @TBL 
SET FixedPath = REPLACE([Path]
        ,LEFT(REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([Path]), 1, CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([Path],1,LEN([Path])-1)))),'\','')),8) + RIGHT(REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([Path]), 1, CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([Path],1,LEN([Path])-1)))),'\','')),LEN(REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([Path]), 1, CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([Path],1,LEN([Path])-1)))),'\','')))-8)
        ,FORMAT(CAST(LEFT(REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([Path]), 1, CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([Path],1,LEN([Path])-1)))),'\','')),8) AS DATE), 'MMddyyyy') + RIGHT(REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([Path]), 1, CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([Path],1,LEN([Path])-1)))),'\','')),LEN(REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([Path]), 1, CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([Path],1,LEN([Path])-1)))),'\','')))-8))

SELECT [Path]
        ,[FixedPath]
FROM @TBL
```

**RESULTS**

| Path | FixedPath |
| --- | --- |
| \ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\201903050012\ | \ImageServer\2019\0121\20190305\030520190012\ |
| \ImageServer\2020\15896215\20200606\20200606852358\ | \ImageServer\2020\15896215\20200606\06062020852358\ |
| \ImageServer\2021\753159\20211209\20211209002585 | \ImageServer\2021\753159\20211209\12092021002585 |